# Sharepoint 2010 Generates Incorrect link on standard form view pages

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I faced with the following issue:

SharePoint 2010 generates following code for look up column on default `DispForm.aspx` page:

```
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="/chernov/_Layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={754EB468-69FB-41D3-B2E4-373C756A4B8D}&ID=29" onclick="EditLink2(this,);return false;" target="_self">Inv#1</a><img src="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif" alt="New" class="ms-newgif" />
```

The issue is that `onclick` handler contains incorrect JavaScript expression: **EditLink2(this,)**.

I found out that the look up field layout is defined in the:

> `<Program Files>`\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL\fldtypes.xsl

in following way:

```
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="{$FORM_DISPLAY}&amp;ID={$ID}" onclick="EditLink2(this,{$ViewCounter});return false;" target="_self">
```

So XSLT transformation cannot resolve a `{$ViewCounter}` parameter properly.

Have anybody faced the issue? What is possible root cause?